# Subset list of text and matching embeddings using set() and np.unique() gives different length results

Tags: python, numpy, sentence-transformers

I have a list of strings, as well as an array containing the dense embeddings generated from those strings (generated using `SentenceTransformer("all-mpnet-base-V2")`). In my  analysis I notice that a number of the strings are repeated text. I want to run my analysis on unique values. Because generating embeddings is expensive, i want to subset my unique strings and get the relevant embeddings. I try this using `set()` and `np.unique()`, but get different length results. Why is this?

I don't post a reproducible example, because my array of vectors is large. But can anyone explain what might be happening and why these lengths wouldn't match, they are close but not the same?

```
#Basic structure of my data:
titles = ["some text", "other text", ...]
embeddings = [Array1, Array2, ...]
#Get unique items of the list
unique_titles = list(set(titles))
unique_embeddings = np.unique(embeddings, axis = 0)
    
len(unique_titles) == len(unique_embeddings)
False
```

I can get around this all with the following for loop:

```
titles_unique = []
embeddings_unique = np.array([0 for i in range(embeddings.shape[1])])
for t, e in zip(titles, embeddings):
    if t not in titles_unique:
        titles_unique.append(t)
        embeddings_unique = np.vstack([embeddings_unique, e])

#Get rid of the first row of the array, used to create the correct number of dimensions
embeddings_unique = np.delete(embeddings_unique, (0), axis = 0)
```

But this is slow and I will have to do this for a much larger data set shortly.

The fact that `set()` and `np.unique()` don't give the same results makes me think i am losing information somewhere.

Comment: That slow loop should not use repeated `vstack`.  Stick with list append to make a growable list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `np.unique(..., return_index=True)` option. See the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

titles = ["some text", "other text", "some text"]
embeddings = [np.asarray([0, 1, 0]), np.asarray([1, 0, 0]), np.asarray([0, 1, 0])]

unique_titles, idx = np.unique(titles, return_index=True)
unique_embeddings = np.array(embeddings)[idx]
    
len(unique_titles) == len(unique_embeddings)
```

Which returns `True`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Axel Donath. Yes, this gets me around the for loop (which is great). At the same time, what is happening such that: `len(np.unique(titles)) == len(np.unique(embeddings, axis = 0))` returns `False`? I generated the embeddings from the text, yet removing duplicates texts and duplicate embeddings does not yield objects of the same length.

Comment: I think the problem with `np.unique(embeddings, axis = 0)` is just the numerical precision. I presume your embedding vectors contain float values, which might slightly differ. So they can only be unique up to a certain numerical precision. You could maybe work around this using `np.allclose`.